# How to load Media from Media server in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, media-player, media

There are issues with media loading speed on my platform, even for little photos, and there is a discernible lag after the application has been running for some time. For storing data, I use Backblaze. I am looking for specific guidance on how to optimize media loading so that it loads almost instantly, like Facebook. Any particular methods, setups, or best practices to speed up loading times would be very appreciated, particularly about graphics. We greatly value your insights!